Using tidyverse to loop or iterate my dataframe to replace all values before the a first specific value and after a specific value
I'm working with psychological tests composed of 10 gradually increasing items. Scores can be 0 (wrong), 1 (almost correct), or 2 (correct answer). So, question 2 is harder than question 1. Question 3 is harder than question 2 and 1, etc. People don't reply to all questions but just to some questions (items). The score system should do this:
-- All columns before the first column with the value equals "2" should be replaced with "2". [We consider that the participant would correctly answer this question]
-- All columns after the last column with the value equals "0" should be replaced with "0". [We consider that the participant would fail this question]
I tried all solutions but I did not have success on this. I would like to stay with tidyverse, using mutate if possible
Dataframe is
df = structure(list(x1_2 = c(NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA), x2_2 = c(NA, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2), x3_2 = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), x4_2 = c(2, 1, 0, 2, 
0, 0), x5_2 = c(2, 1, NA, 2, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
df

Desidered dataframe is:
df_final = structure(list(x1_2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), x2_2 = c(2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2), x3_2 = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), x4_2 = c(2, 1, 0, 2, 
    0, 0), x5_2 = c(2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
df_final


For all first values, I could use this code:
initialNA <- function(x) {
  index <- cumsum(is.na(x)) >= seq_along(x)
  x[index] <- 2
  x
}

df <- data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, initialNA)))
df


please clarify what would be a 'first' 2, and a 'last' 0.

You could modify your function slightly as follows:

Include a second chunk of code to impute the trailing NA, similar to your existing code, but simply reversing the vectors.

Replace x[index] <- 2 with x[index] <- max(x, na.rm=TRUE) since an individual may get a question only "almost correct".


The final function looks like this:
imputeNA <- function(x) {
  index1 <- cumsum(is.na(x)) >= seq_along(x)
  x[index1] <- max(x, na.rm=TRUE)

  index2 <- rev(cumsum(rev(is.na(x))) >= seq_along(x))
  x[index2] <- min(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  x
}

Now, modify your toy data slightly so that the first guy has all "ones" instead "twos" in order to better test the function.
df[1,] <- data.frame(NA, NA, 1, 1, 1)
df

   x1_2  x2_2  x3_2  x4_2  x5_2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA    NA     1     1     1
2     2     2     2     1     1
3    NA     2     1     0    NA
4    NA     2     1     2     2
5    NA     2     2     0    NA
6    NA     2     2     0    NA

Test it:
data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, imputeNA)))

  x1_2 x2_2 x3_2 x4_2 x5_2
1    1    1    1    1    1
2    2    2    2    1    1
3    2    2    1    0    0
4    2    2    1    2    2
5    2    2    2    0    0
6    2    2    2    0    0


That was great! Thanks! Just to make it clear: "rev" is to run the function backwards. "t" transposes the dataframe; "apply" loop over all dataframe, and the number "1" is something that is obscure for me. I'm more used to tidyverse environment. (By the way, you're always helping me. thank you so much)

Calling the function was your code, not mine. ;)  The "1" in the second argument of apply (the MARGIN) tells R to loop over the rows, as opposed to the columns ("2") or both ("c(1,2)").

Using the dplyr and tidyr packages:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) |>
  group_by(id) |>
  fill(value, .direction = "downup") |>
  ungroup() |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,
              values_from = value) |>
  select(-id)

# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#    x1_2  x2_2  x3_2  x4_2  x5_2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2     2     2     2     2
# 2     2     2     2     1     1
# 3     2     2     1     0     0
# 4     2     2     1     2     2
# 5     2     2     2     0     0
# 6     2     2     2     0     0


You can define a helper function for use inside mutate() that uses max.col(), col(), and is.na() to find the indices of the values to be replaced and uses < or > for left and right side replacement:
library(dplyr)

rf <- function(cols, value, FUN) {
  dat <- pick({{ cols }})
  nadat <- is.na(dat)
  replace(dat, 
          FUN(col(dat), max.col(cbind(dat == value & !nadat, TRUE), "first")) & nadat, 
          value)
}

df |> 
  mutate(rf(ends_with("_2"), 2, `<`),
         rf(ends_with("_2"), 0, `>`))

# A tibble: 6 × 5
   x1_2  x2_2  x3_2  x4_2  x5_2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     2     2     2     2
2     2     2     2     1     1
3     2     2     1     0     0
4     2     2     1     2     2
5     2     2     2     0     0
6     2     2     2     0     0

